# How to get info from a public Trello board

Tags: json, lua, trello

I'm wondering how would I get cards in a list on a public board on Trello.
For example, for private board, you need API key and token, but what about for public boards?

Comment: Did you try making a request without an API key and token? What happened?

Comment: With the API key and token, it works, but it doesn't work without it even though the board is public. If I try in the browser, it works fine with or without it.

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question, then? Yes, it seems that API key and token are needed for API requests for public boards.

Comment: Yeah, but why don't we need it in a browser?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"in a browser"*. If you mean how you can see a public board, presumably that's not making the same API requests you are.